# Center a UIView vertically and horizontally within its parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview, frame

I have a UICollection view that is inside another UIView. I am trying to center the collection view inside its parent view. Currently manually doing it by tweaking its frame (see code below). There has to be a easier way.

CURRENT CODE:

```
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(COLLECTION_PADDING+10, COLLECTION_PADDING+5, self.bounds.size.width - (COLLECTION_PADDING*2), self.bounds.size.height - (COLLECTION_PADDING+22)) collectionViewLayout:flow];
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How are you creating and positioning the view?  Are you using interface builder?  Autolayout?  Struts?  A whole lot of missing information here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
self.collectionView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(superview.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(superview.bounds));
```

**Swift 3:**

```
self.collectionView.center = CGPoint(superview.bounds.midX, superview.bounds.midY)
```

With this approach, your subview will be centered in its superview regardless of the superview's coordinates.  Using an approach like this:

```
self.collectionView.center = superview.center
```

Will cause problems if the superview has an origin of anything other than 0,0

Comment: with swift 4.2: self.collectionView.center = CGPoint(x: superview.bounds.midX, y: superview.bounds.midY)

Answer (score 3):

You can setup your collectionView's width and height and then use the `center` property to adjust it's location.

```
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];
self.collectionView.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x,self.center.y);
```

EDIT:
As Logan just mentioned in the comments, this only works if self and self.collectionView have the same superview.  If you are adding collectionView to a view and want it centered inside that view then you could do:

```
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];
self.collectionView.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x - self.frame.origin.x/2,self.center.y - self.frame.origin.x/2);
```

But this case doesn't work when there is rotation involved.  In that case you would have to use other means.  So, as anything in coding, this is not a clear cut answer.  But for most cases it will work.  If you are getting into the rare cases that it does not work then you are likely going to do more custom framing than just centering inside parents.

Comment: While this will often work, there is a problem when the superview has an origin of something other than 0,0.  Alternate situations will cause problems.  Also, `CGPointMake(self.center.x,self.center.y);` is equal to `self.center`.

Answer (score 2):

Heard of Layouts?..This might help you.

This is for horizontal alignment

```
NSLayoutConstraint *centerHcons =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:collectionViewSuper attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
```

This is for vertical alignment

```
NSLayoutConstraint *centerVcons =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:collectionViewSuper attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];

    [collectionViewSuper addConstraints:@[centerHcons, centerVcons]];
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you could try finding the difference between your collectionview and your parent view size.  Then dividing by 2 and padding all sides with that.

```
parentHeight = self.bounds.size.height;
parentWidth = self.bounds.size.width;
heightDiff = parentHeight - collectionview.bounds.size.height;
widthDiff = parentWidth - collectionview.bounds.size.width;
heightPadding = heightDiff/2;
widthPadding = widthDiff/2;

self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(widthPadding, heightPadding, parentWidth-widthPadding, parentHeight-heightPadding) collectionViewLayout:flow];
```

Comment: Scratch that, Putz' answer is better.  Ignore me :)

Comment: Not necessarily better, just simpler.  People seem to like simpler.